# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seem to be having a problem with this module that was exported in the correct manner but when it is imported and i get the error that was stated above. can anyone help? anything is appreciated
Here is the code of the module

```
    import React from "react";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import Typography from "material-ui/styles/typography";

    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      maindiv: {
        float: 'left',
          },
     }));

    export default function Home() {
     console.log("inside the function");
     const classes = useStyles();
      return (
       <div className={classes.maindiv}>
         <Typography variant="h5">this is it</Typography>
       </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: can you show how u r using it.. and if there is an working example or link to hosted urls would be better for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'Typography' import is wrong.
Use 
import {Typography} from '@material-ui/core';
instead of
import Typography from "material-ui/styles/typography";